# Lucene SpanNearQuery with composite words in java

Tags: java, lucene

I'm having a problem with the `SpanNearQuery` in Lucene 4.3.
I'm trying to do a query like this:

```
SpanTermQuery fleeceQ = new SpanTermQuery(new Term("content", "golden fleece"));
SpanTermQuery blackQ = new SpanTermQuery(new Term("content", "black"));
SpanQuery[] clauses = {fleeceQ, blackQ};
SpanNearQuery nearQ = new SpanNearQuery(clauses, 10, false);
```

In the field "content" of my document I have:
"History looks fondly upon the black story of the golden fleece, but most people don't agree"

Well, what happens is that the query returns me nothing. But if I change "golden fleece" to "fleece" it works, so I guess the problem is with the composite words.

I'm using the `SpanNearQuery` because I have to do a proximity search and I need to know how many times it occurs.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that "golden fleece" is Not a term.  It's two terms, `golden` and `fleece`.  When you construct the term yourself though, with:

```
new Term("content", "golden fleece")
```

It will take your word for it, and make it a single term.  There are no matches, because the single term `golden fleece` doesn't exist in your index.

There isn't a clear way to incorporate a `PhraseQuery` into a `SpanNearQuery`, so I think it might make sense to create another, nested, `SpanNearQuery` to create the behavior you are looking for:

```
SpanTermQuery goldenQ = new SpanTermQuery(new Term("content", "golden"));
SpanTermQuery fleeceQ = new SpanTermQuery(new Term("content", "fleece"));
SpanTermQuery blackQ = new SpanTermQuery(new Term("content", "black"));

SpanQuery[] subclauses = {goldenQ, fleeceQ};
SpanNearQuery goldfleeceQ = new SpanNearQuery(subclauses, 0, true); //No slop, in order!

SpanQuery[] mainclauses = {goldfleeceQ, blackQ};
SpanNearQuery finalQ = new SpanNearQuery(mainclauses, 10, false); //As before, 10 slop, any order
```

Comment: Thank you very much man!
I don't know how I didn't think about that!
Thanks a lot!